# How to unregister incoming call and outgoing call receivers?

Tags: android, receiver

I'm developing an application for Android.
I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with original ROM Jelly Bean 4.3.

I have a problem with the receivers of incoming call and outgoing call.

Here is the code of IncomingCallReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        if (Start.getMusicService().isPlaying()) {
            pauseMusicService();

            isMusicPlaying = true;
        }
    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        if (isMusicPlaying){
            restartMusicService();
            isMusicPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not the problem, this code works and also the outgoing call receiver works perfectly.

My problem is that when i exit the application this receivers still work.

It's happened that, days after the last time i opened the application, i received a phone call and the application crashed.

I think that it's happened because i write the code:

```
if (Start.getMusicService().isPlaying())
```

because Start (my first activity) doesn't exist.

I never register this receiver, they work without that i "call" them.
I don't know if i have to unregister and in case when i have to do it.

So, can anyone help me please?

Andrea

Comment: Is the Intent's receiver registered in your AndroidManifest or at runtime?

Comment: @DanS yes, i declare the two receivers on manifest and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a `BroadcastReceiver` or other `Intent` receiver in your `AndroidManifest` it is always "on". Move the registration and deregistration to the beginning and end of the execution of your app, or other times in your app; then you will be able to control when its on at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. If you want to register and/or unregister receiver yourself at  you should register in onResume and unregister in onPause in case of activity. Look out this example http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html